# Formal name of the tetrahedron with five edges of length $1/\sqrt2$ and one edge of length $1$?

Tags: geometry

I tried to find the exact name of this tetrahedron but failed.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd9Cv.jpg]

It is composed of five edges with its length $1/\sqrt{2}$ and one edge with its length $1$.

If we subtract a "stellated octahedron" from a cube, we can obtain $12$ congruent ones associated with each edge of the cube.

Does anyone know the formal name of this tetrahedron?

Comment: FYI, the closest name I got is "digonal disphenoid."

Comment: Here's a basic [interactive plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jtEKgzAMRd8F_-G-aVmRbSKMQf_Bd_HBaZ1l2pS2IOzrlw43AuEEbk4ye9oQhqeu3Erx2-qpCsvgdLjCbI58xOyHTddTnrkIha48Sy4hUV5-UDVMVXNgmkSfZy2nj93Sxe7cf1e4hMizmTwcjIWLd7Q4KTgyNqaoRDBvrW4SI63kVeH1VIjk49RqbPJ1LDQ9ksUkCz-Fi8RVgqH-cS34ZlzM-LI6BNX8jQ9Pu03OsNBetuIDRwhJFg==&lang=sage), using Sage. Hold the shift key while moving the mouse to pan.